# Seeking GeoJSON resources files

Tags: geojson, data, csv

I'm looking for demographic information and various things, and most of the time data are available as CSV (my application use geoJSON format).

Shall I encode the CSV to geoJSON or is there a "library" for geoJSON or some kind of a database of geojson files ?

Comment: http://www.geojson.org/geojson-spec.html

Comment: Ah yes this the spec for geoJson, useful :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use python, you can handle csv file for generating geojson from it....

the basic way:

```
import csv, json

file = open( 'test.csv', 'r' )
reader = csv.DictReader( file , fieldnames = ( "id","name","attribute","lat","lng" ) )
outfile = json.dumps( [ row for row in reader ] )

print outfile

out = open("output.txt", "w")
out.write(outfile) 
out.close()
```

the other way is from Andrew Dyck [here](http://www.andrewdyck.com/how-to-convert-csv-data-to-geojson/) with using geojson template which u created:

```
import csv

# Read in raw data from csv
rawData = csv.reader(open('sample.csv', 'rb'), dialect='excel')

# the template. where data from the csv will be formatted to geojson
template = \
    ''' \
    { "type" : "Feature",
        "id" : %s,
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : ["%s","%s"]},
        "properties" : { "name" : "%s", "value" : "%s"}
        },
    '''

# the head of the geojson file
output = \
    ''' \
{ "type" : "Feature Collection",
    {"features" : [
    '''

# loop through the csv by row skipping the first
iter = 0
for row in rawData:
    iter += 1
    if iter >= 2:
        id = row[0]
        lat = row[1]
        lon = row[2]
        name = row[3]
        pop = row[4]
        output += template % (row[0], row[2], row[1], row[3], row[4])

# the tail of the geojson file
output += \
    ''' \
    ]
}
    '''

# opens an geoJSON file to write the output to
outFileHandle = open("output.geojson", "w")
outFileHandle.write(output)
outFileHandle.close()
```

Comment: there is also a [geojson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/geojson/1.0) specific python library in addition to the json library.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only concerned with point data, Aragon's example is perfect.  For more complex shapes you will need a bit more.

You can use ogr2ogr to convert *nearly* any type of data to geoJSON.  I would employ some quality checks before relying on the conversion.

```
ogr2ogr -f geoJSON out.json in.shp
```

If you're more comfortable with a GUI, qGIS uses the same methods but it's easier to view / modify your process.  qGIS can also help you import data from a CSV.

Comment: I briefly used qGIS in the past but didn't realize it could convert shapefile/csv to geoJson ! I'll give a try to ogr2ogr.

Comment: I haven't used it in a while, but I think its in the file types under File > Save As.